# Attempting to find the average time spent in a specific mode per day

Tags: azure-sql-database

I've been asked to find the amount of time spent between various modes of a system on a daily basis. The database has a table that provides a starting datetime and updates every 15 minutes, providing a number that references a specific mode type.

## TABLE ModeTimes

| UID | TimeSpent | Mode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2010-01-01 16:00:00 | 1 |
| 123 | 2010-01-01 16:15:00 | 1 |
| 123 | 2010-01-01 16:30:00 | 2 |
| 123 | 2010-01-01 16:45:00 | 3 |
| 456 | 2010-01-01 16:00:00 | 1 |
| 123 | 2010-01-01 17:15:00 | 3 |
| 123 | 2010-01-01 17:30:00 | 3 |
| 123 | 2010-01-01 17:45:00 | 1 |
| 123 | 2010-01-01 18:00:00 | 2 |
| 123 | 2010-01-01 18:15:00 | 4 |
| 123 | 2010-01-01 18:30:00 | 4 |
| 123 | 2010-01-01 18:45:00 | 4 |

What I am working towards is:

| UID | Date | Mode | TotalMinutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2010-01-01 | 1 | 60 |
| 123 | 2010-01-01 | 2 | 30 |
| 123 | 2010-01-01 | 3 | 45 |
| 123 | 2010-01-01 | 4 | 45 |
| 456 | 2010-01-01 | 1 | 15 |

I've found the total minutes for each mode for all entries in the table, but I cannot figure out how to break that down further:

```
select UID,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(TimeSpent), MAX(TimeSpent), MIN(TimeSpent)) TimeSpentInMinutes,
    Mode
from ModeTimes
group by UID, Mode
```

It feels like I'm right there, but I haven't done SQL in a minute and I haven't been too successful in my search terms.
Any help would be very appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: "*but I cannot figure out how to break that down further*" - What do you mean by this? At quick glance your query and description appears to match your example table. (Though I think you might have one too many parameters in the `DATEDIFF()` function?)

Comment: You were correct about the DATEDIFF params. Needed some switch up. I've marked the answer below as correct, but I appreciate the quick check and comment. Any help is valuable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with a as (
select UID,
    CAST(TimeSpent as date) as [Date],
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE,TimeSpent,LAG(TimeSpent) OVER(ORDER BY UID, TimeSpent DESC)) as Minutes,
    Mode
from ModeTimes
)
select
    UID,
    [Date],
    Mode,
    SUM(Minutes) as TotalMinutes
FROM a
group by UID, [Date], Mode
order by UID, [Date], Mode
```

Comment: This was absolutely fantastic, thank you!!! Did exactly what was needed and got some great responses from those that wanted it. (Doesn't help much, but I gave credit where due. Thanks again!!!)